# Unable to mount "lvm2" volume

Tags: centos, lvm, mount

I had to reinstall CentOS on a system with a separate disk array for data.  I installed on the OS disks and kept the other disk array as storage (so they were not formatted).

When I try to mount the disks, I'm blocked due to unknown filesystem lvm2.

First some background.  The system has two arrays of drives.  One is for the OS (CentOS 6), the other for Data.   Here is the physical disk count on the machine:

```
#   Description                                     Total Gigs
2   HARD DRIVE, 300GB, SAS6, 10, 2.5, H-CE, E/C      600
6   HARD DRIVE, 600G, SAS6, 10, 2.5, W-SIR, E/C     3600
```

The two smaller drives are mirrored as 300g - this is where the OS lives.

The volume names are not listed when using `pvs`

```
PV          VG       Fmt  Att PSize  PFree
/dev/sda5   vg_ursula lvm2 a-- 276g   0
/dev/sdb1            lvm2 --- 1.8t   1.8t
/dev/sdc1            lvm2 --- 948g   948.67g
```

The PSize and PFree lines worry me.

Here's output from `pvscan`

```
  PV /dev/sda5   VG vg_ursula   lvm2 [276.34 GiB / 0    free]
  PV /dev/sdb1                  lvm2 [1.80 TiB]
  PV /dev/sdc1                  lvm2 [948.67 GiB]
  Total: 3 [3.00 TiB] / in use: 1 [276.34 GiB] / in no VG: 2 [2.73 TiB]
```

and `lvscan`

```
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vg_ursula/LogVol05' [29.30 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vg_ursula/LogVol04' [48.83 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vg_ursula/LogVol03' [48.83 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vg_ursula/lv_root' [111.74 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vg_ursula/lv_home' [9.77 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vg_ursula/lv_swap' [27.89 GiB] inherit
```

and `vgscan`

```
  Reading all physical volumes.  This may take a while...
  Found volume group "vg_ursula" using metadata type lvm2
```

partial output from `vgck -vvv`.

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/076cd514c42ec1d0d356

`file -s /dev/sdb1`

```
/dev/sdb1: LVM2 (Linux Logical Volume Manager) , UUID: B1bLeFveeDcnfZ2i0tuqWtHgSd6UAgM
```

`file -s /dev/sdc1`

```
/dev/sdc1: LVM2 (Linux Logical Volume Manager) , UUID: SMMVLUKEuBPHuTeoarMkDAlJDDY1Gm2
```

and

`pvdisplay /dev/sdb1`

```
  "/dev/sdb1" is a new physical volume of "1.80 TiB"
  --- NEW Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdb1
  VG Name               
  PV Size               1.80 TiB
  Allocatable           NO
  PE Size               0   
  Total PE              0
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          0
  PV UUID               B1bLeF-veeD-cnfZ-2i0t-uqWt-HgSd-6UAgMA
```

`pvdisplay /dev/sdc1`

```
  "/dev/sdc1" is a new physical volume of "948.67 GiB"
  --- NEW Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdc1
  VG Name               
  PV Size               948.67 GiB
  Allocatable           NO
  PE Size               0   
  Total PE              0
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          0
  PV UUID               SMMVLU-KEuB-PHuT-eoar-MkDA-lJDD-Y1Gm2g
```

When installing this OS, I only moved the 276g drive to the "Install" list and left the other two as storage only.  When I reviewed the format/partition settigns, the two storage drives did not have a check under the Format column.

[image]

What are my next steps to mount and get the data from the other drives?

Comment: Have you activated all of your lv volumes? vgchange -a

Comment: Will `vgchange` work noting that there are no volume names listed?

Comment: Whats the output of pvscan and lvscan ?

Comment: do you have any copy of the vgmetadata for restoring the vg?

Comment: @Alpha01 I've added pvscan and lvscan to the question.

Comment: @c4f4t0r - I do not.

Comment: Can you also include the output of vgscan? Were the /dev/sdb1 and /dev/sdc1 PVs part of a differ Volume Group and not part of vg_ursula?

Comment: @Alpha01 to be honest I do not have adequate documentation to show how these drives were set up during install several years ago and am trying to piece it together now.

Comment: I've added output from `vgscan`.

Comment: Man, I hope you have a back up of whatever was in /dev/sd[b-c]1. Run `vgck -vvv` and provide gist link to the output (it may be long)

Comment: I am going to try hard not to commit suicide tonight.   Backups were silently failing due to another issue that led to rebuild of the box.  The OS was hosed, couldn't connect anywhere, no yum updates, even ping localhost failed.   It all started with an innocent yum update on Sept 10.

Comment: `vgck -vvv &> outout.txt`

Comment: Here is the full `vgck -vvv` output.  https://gist.github.com/anonymous/25ddd3280a34364fa186

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29463/discussion-between-alpha01-and-a-coder).